# Modifying NFS (XFS) File Attributes from within Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, nfs, xfs

Scenario: 
I'm on Server 2008 R2 and I've mapped a network drive using Services for Network File System (NFS).  I've mounted the drive to "N:" (for NFS or NAS) using the mount command line utility ([source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780851%28WS.10%29.aspx)), specifying the "-o fileaccess=7" option, and using the Admin user.  This gives me the ability to modify the files however I need to on the server (rights aren't an issue).

```
mount N: -o fileaccess=7 -u:admin -p:password 192.168.1.14:/mnt/array1
```

The file attributes and persmissions inside the files are typical XFS persmissions, I'm assuming my Buffalo Terastation is running some form of Linux under the hood (but I don't have root access to verify or poke around).

I need to modify the permissions from within windows.  I can right click on the individual files in Windows Explorer under N: and change the checkboxes for Owner(RWX) Group(RWX) and Other(RWX) however I want since I mounted it using an account with sufficient rights, but I need to automate applying a specific set of permissions to all files in all directories so that the Other class will have full access.

I've investigated using icacls (command line) and using set-acl (powershell), but I haven't been able to come up with a way to do this.  If I can't do this within windows I'll setup a linux server and mount the NFS there and use chmod (bash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this to copy newly created files on a weekly basis I reworked the strategy entirely.  Instead of storing the files on the Buffalo Terastation I'm keeping them on a separate server entirely with the server being added to vSphere being managed by vCenter.